# HTML5 Multiple H2 tags

Tags: html, tags, html-heading

Can I get away with the following:

```
<div id="titles">
 <h1>Main Title</h1>
 <h2>Subtitle One</h2>
 <h2>Subtitle Two</h2>
 <h2>Subtitle Three</h2>
</div>
```

With no paragraphs or h3/h4 tags in between the H2s? Or is it better to wrap all the three titles into one H2 tag using spans and breaks? They are main three services offered by client.

Thanks!

Comment: You can, but it all depends on what your desired output is and how you style them.

Comment: Your code is html5 valid.

Answer (score 0):

If `Subtitle Two` is independent of `Subtitle One` I would put them in separate H2 tags.

Visit [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp) to learn more about HTML Headings.

Since it is just plain HTML you can do whatever you want. It's completely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to have them as `h2` it would be best to have them as separate tags  because that structures the page better and makes it easier to edit the individual subtitles using css etc.

A better option would be to have the subtitles as an unordered list. For example:

```
<div id="titles">
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Subtitle One</li>
        <li>Subtitle Two</li>
        <li>Subtitle Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And style it like this to make it look like `h2`:

```
<style type="text/css">
#titles ul {
    list-style: none;
}
#titles ul li {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
}
</style>
```

This is better for search engines and code readability.

> Search engines use the headings to index the structure and content of
>   your web pages.
>
> Users skim your pages by its headings. It is important to use headings
>   to show the document structure.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp